# Problem about create IKfast plugin for moveit in ROS noetic and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: moveit, inverse-kinematics, ros-noetic, ikfast

According the tutorial from [MoveIt website](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/ikfast/ikfast_tutorial.html)

There can't install openrave on ROS noetic, so I use the docker to pull this image from this [website](https://hub.docker.com/r/personalrobotics/ros-openrave)

I can install this image successly, but I don't know how to continue to use this openrave which is in the docker to create IKfast plugin for my moveit which is install on my real Ubuntu 20.04

I can't search the helpful tutorial about use openrave in docker to create IKfast plugin
Does anyone know the detailed process to create IKfast plugin?
I stuck at this step for 3 days, need some help

Thank you!!